# Javascript / ES6 find unique elements and count them in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Take an imaginary array of sold items where we oddly enough only are interested in the item title and value:

```
let items = [
    { title: "Trumping the Horns", value: 5.95 },
    { title: "Rocking about", value: 20.00 },
    { title: "Trumping the Horns", value: 5.95 }
]
```

I know I can get an array with the unique values rather easily:

```
const uniqueSales = [...new Set(items.map(item => item.title))];
```

But lets for instance say I want to know how many of each item I have sold, or the accumulated value of them? So:

```
[
    { title: "Trumping the Horns", amount: 2 },
    { title: "Rocking about", amount: 1 }
]
```

Is it possible to map those as well, without having to do some crazy sorting and iterating over that array? Preferebly in a one-liner. The main reason for not doing it server side is that I have a fair amount of different manipulations of the same data, and it seems most correct to just send it once and let the client handle the manipulations and presentations of the data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and store the reference to the new inserted objects of the result array.

```js
var items = [{ title: "Trumping the Horns", value: 5.95 }, { title: "Rocking about", value: 20.00 }, { title: "Trumping the Horns", value: 5.95 }],
    result = items.reduce(
        (map => (r, a) => (!map.has(a.title) && map.set(a.title, r[r.push({ title: a.title, amount: 0 }) - 1]), map.get(a.title).amount++, r))(new Map),
        []
    );

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Beautiful - tyvm.

Answer (score 3):

In ES6, we can get returned unique items from a single line of code as below,

```
// with arrays
const dupArr = [1, 1, 2, 3, 1];
const uniArr = [...(new Set(dupArr))];
// [1, 2, 3]

// with objects on a key.
const dupObj = [{ id: 1, value: 'a' }, { id: 2, value: 'b' }, { id: 1, value: 'c' }];
const uniKeys = [...(new Set(dupObj.map(({ id }) => id)))];
// [ '1', '2' ]
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
let items = [{
    title: "Trumping the Horns",
    value: 5.95
  },
  {
    title: "Rocking about",
    value: 20.00
  },
  {
    title: "Trumping the Horns",
    value: 5.95
  }
];

console.log(items.reduce(function(countMap, item) {
  countMap[item.title] = ++countMap[item.title] || 1;
  return countMap;
}, {}));
```

Comment: This doesn't produce the output the OP said he wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Given the format you want in the end, I don't think it gets much shorter than using a `Map` to build up objects with the `title` and `amount`, then grabbing the `Map`'s values:

```js
const items = [
    { title: "Trumping the Horns", value: 5.95 },
    { title: "Rocking about", value: 20.00 },
    { title: "Trumping the Horns", value: 5.95 }
];
const map = new Map();
items.forEach(item => {
  const entry = map.get(item.title);
  if (!entry) {
    map.set(item.title, {title: item.title, amount: 1});
  } else {
    ++entry.amount;
  }
});
const uniqueSales = [...map.values()];
console.log(uniqueSales);
```

> ...preferably a one-liner...

The above can be shoehorned into fewer lines, but it doesn't improve speed, readability, or maintainability. Quite the opposite.

Comment: Totally agree with the one-liner. Was probably a bad choice of words, my point was mostly to keep it as concise as possible and only having the least amount of, and most reasonable, steps.

Comment: @Dennis: It's worth noting that Nina's solution is less efficient than the above (unnecessary key lookup), purely so she can shoehorn it into expressions rather than statements. Now, 99.9999% of the time you don't care, but it's an example of how fewer statements != most efficient, least number of steps solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a map rather than an array for storing your items, where the key of the map should be the title of the item, and the value should be the quantity of the sold items. Each time, before you add a new item to the map, you should check, whether the key already exist, and if it does, then increase the quantity, otherwise add a new key-value pair to the map.

Answer (score 0):

```
 let array = [{title:"123"}, {title: "234"}, {title: "123"}]
 let sum = array.reduce((results, item, index) => {
                      let totalItem = results.find((element) =>
                            element.title == item.title)
                      if(totalItem){
                        totalItem.count += 1
                      }else {
                         results.push(Object.assign(item, {
                              count: 1
                            }))
                      }
                       return results
                     }, [])
```

use array reduce to generate new array

Answer (score 0):

```
const ages = [3,1,1,2,3,4,1,2,3]
ages.sort();
console.log(ages);
const uniqueAges = ages.find((x, i) => {if(x!=ages[i-1]&&x!=ages[i+1]){
return x;
}} )
console.log(uniqueAges);

Output 
4
```